# Is the DeLorean in "Back to the Future" able to determine the present time?

Tags: movie, back-to-the-future

Whenever you travel through time the DeLorean updates the time circuits to reflect the current date and time. How does it know the current date and time of its arrived destination?

I guess what I am asking is, when the lighting stuck the delorean and jumped it back to 1885. Did the time circuits *know* it was 1885, or did it not know, because it wasn't entered.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. You program in the time for the destination.

Comment: Sorry, I have adjusted the question.

Comment: That is a really interesting question.

Comment: I'd guess it's like a odometer; it knows how far it went through time.

Comment: @GabeWillard ok, any ideas how it does that?

Comment: Nope, that's why it's a comment. :P I don't think the inner workings of the DeLorean's 4th dimensional engine are ever discussed, but presumably, it works like a real engine. A real engine is basically like, 10000 spins of the tires are one mile (pulled that stat out of my backside), so maybe, 10000 blinks of the Flux Capacitor are one year? Purely theorizing.

Comment: @JackBNimble The flux capacitor obviously. Just kidding.

Comment: When you think about it, there is no such thing as the present time.  By the fact that in the BTTF universe time travel is possible, it means that it is always the present - what I mean by that is that all time (1885, 1955, 1985, 2015) are all simultaneously occurring - on what basis would you say that 1985 was the present time when you were in 1955?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Before the lightning hits, you can see the time circuit experiencing bugs and the destination date continually changing between 1955 and 1885 (as you can see in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUkdSHTd_FM#t=0m47s) video). Obviously, we can assume it settled on 1885 since this is when it sent the DeLorean. The date was thus "entered", even if it wasn't intentionally. As to your question, I believe the time circuit, once the time travel has been completed, sets the current time as being the same as the destination time used in the voyage.

A clock doesn't "know" what time it is. It simply calculates how much time has passed since a certain reference point. If you give it a new reference point, such as by changing the current time it displays, it will simply update from that point on. How it calculates time varies greatly depending on the type of clock, but, in 1985, the year the movie was made and originally set, computers and electronical items were already able to keep track of the passage of time through internal clocks.

The DeLorean can safely be assumed to possess one such internal clock and, therefore, keep track of time. When the DeLorean was struck by lightening, the time circuit's clock most likely adjusted it's current time to JAN 01, 1885, 12:00AM after completing the voyage. From then on, it kept updating the current time just like any other clock.

Answer (score 1):

It knows what time it is because when you travel through time, you input where your going and then it goes there. That's how it knows. If your asking how it knew the first time around, then I'm sure that Doc just put in what the original present time was.